# How to access .aspx pages in android WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm doing a website to Android app,but .aspx page to webview is not loading, I got white screen.

## MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());

        String url = "https://something.aspx";

        wv.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

## myWebViewClient

```
class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    }
}
```

How to load .aspx page in android WebView please solve my issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read this part for shouldOverrideUrlLoading in docs? `return true means the host application handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles the url. `

Comment: you are explicit excluding `aspx` from beeing displayed. remove your if condition in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and just return false

Comment: @Fusselchen I tried it but not working

Comment: after removing the aspx filter, you should either see the page, or something in your log, like missing permission or some other exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the code below in your `myWebViewClient` class:

`@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }`